# Error with Tar2RubyScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following this How-To on Distributing Rails Applications

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html

However, by the time I do:

```
$ ruby tar2rubyscript.rb desktopApp/
```

The output is:

```
tar2rubyscript.rb:623:in `replace': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:623:in `block in <main>'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:577:in `block in newlocation'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:505:in `block in newlocation'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:472:in `newlocation'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:505:in `newlocation'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:577:in `newlocation'
        from tar2rubyscript.rb:621:in `<main>'
```